# Find similar string in longer strings

Tags: php, string

Let's assume I have strings like these (it's PHP and German, but neither technical nor lingual language really matters):

```
$longString1 = 'Aber Max v. maex war nicht da.';

$longString2 = 'Von Mäx Maimilian war auch nicht da.';

$longString3 = 'Grüner Apfel';

$longString4 = 'Maximilian von Maex war da!';

$name = 'Maximilian von Mäx';
```

Knowing for $longstring1 e.g.

1. `Max` is an abbreviation of `Maximilian` (means it's sharing first 3 letters)
2. `v.` is an abbrevation of `von` (means it's sharing first letter and stands before `Mäx`)
3. `maex` equals `Mäx` if one doesn't care about case and replaces all `ä` by `ae` upfront

**How can I *estimate* whether `$name` is existing within `$longString`?**

I know all implementations existing in PHP like [Levenshtein](http://php.net/manual/de/function.levenshtein.php), [SimilarText](http://php.net/manual/de/function.similar-text.php) and so on to calculate the similarity for two given strings - but I have no idea how to identify `Max v. saex` as part of the $longString1 which is interesting to compare to my `$name`.

I am looking for a function which returns like:

```
 function ($name, $longString) {

   return $similarity;

   // returns ~0.6 for $longString1
   // returns ~0.7 (of 1) for $longString2
   // returns 0 (of 1) for $longString3
   // returns 1 (of 1) for $longString4
 }
```

** **UPDATE** **

I know that e.g. [Levenshtein](http://php.net/manual/de/function.levenshtein.php) calculates the similarity between two Strings, but it will return a huge difference for this simplified situation:

```
$longString1 = 'Max da.'; // pretty similar
$longString2 = 'Max war heute nicht da.'; // not really similar
$name = 'Max';
```

So it's a two-step requirement here:

1. Identify 'something like *Max*' in $longString
2. Compare 'something like *Max*' with $name for similarity

And I am interested in Step 1 for the most part.

Comment: What you want is not easy, You need mappings in a way for stuff like `v. => von`, because `Max is an abbreviation of Maximilian` can also be  `Maximums` or not;-).You have to create hardcoded mappings.  But php has function that can help you: similiar_text(), levenshtein(), soundex(), metaphone().  http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php

Comment: thanks, as written in OP i understand similar_text() and others. but they don't help me. I'll update the question.

Comment: You have to create a wight system (like if strlen == strlen 1 point else 0.5 and so on) that does some checks and reacts on that. And for `How can I estimate whether $name is existing within $longString` you just can splitt the search-word by space and check all 3 parts against the long, Or first 1 part, then  1 and secon part. depends heavy on what you want to. And you have only posted on example.

Comment: it's really not easy, I think it's best to generated an array with all possible options for "Maximilian von Mäx" so your method signature would become `function ($possibilities, $content)` and in the method you iterate through the possibilities and do an `stripos` on the $content. You could pre define the weight for every possibility.